# Why array with reduce show only one element in a new array?

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have this function

```
let arr = [1849, 81, 64, 36, 25, 16, 9, 9, 4, 1, 0];
    
function reducy(arr){
        return arr.reduce((prevVal, item, index) => {
            prevVal.push(prevVal + item * index);
            return prevVal;
        }, []);
    }
```

console show this:

```
//[
  '0',
  '081',
  '0,081128',
  '0,081,0,081128108',
  '0,081,0,081128,0,081,0,081128108100',
```

but i need:

```
[0, 81, 128, 108, 100, 80, 54, 63, 32, 9, 0]
```

help me please!

Comment: I think you have string concat here. Could you share your input `arr` too?

Comment: yes, here: [1849, 81, 64, 36, 25, 16,  9,  9, 4,  1,  0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prevVal.push(prevVal + item * index)
```

Your problem is you stack value with `prevVal` which is an array.

The fix should be

```
prevVal.push(item * index)
```

Full change

```js
const data = [1849, 81, 64, 36, 25, 16, 9, 9, 4, 1, 0]

function reducy(arr){
    return arr.reduce((prevVal, item, index) => {
        prevVal.push(item * index);
        return prevVal;
    }, []);
}

console.log(reducy(data))
```